# Importing several XML files (with the same elements) into combined MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have several XML files, all of the format:

```
 <story id="12349">
   <name>Reviews</name>
   <slug>reviews</slug>
   <categories>
     <category primary="1">cat1</category>
     <category>cat2</category>
   </categories>
 </story>
```

How can I import them all into a MySQL database (ideally using PHP, as this is what I know best) which will let me edit the `<category>` elements? I'm imagining I want one table with a field for the id and a field for the complete XML, and another with a field for the id and fields for each of the `<category>` elements, though am open to any other suggestions.

Many thanks...

Comment: What do you want to do with the table once the data is in there? If you just want to edit the category element, it may be simpler just to read the data in, modify it and write it out. If the data is going to drive some other service, you'll want to set up a proper relational schema to hold it.

Comment: @Dae I want a human to be able to quickly go through the list of stories adding new categories to them, then export the results back to the XML files. I figured the simplest way to do this would be to write a simple PHP/MySQL frontend, although I suppose if I lumped everything into one table they could use PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out simple xml to parse the xml into an array which you can then push to a DB with simple insert statments within a foreach loop.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the following table structures:

```
Stories table { name => varchar , slug => varchar , id => int }
Categories table {name => varchar, id => int}
LinkStoryCategories table { story_id => int , category_id => int }
```

Then you need to parse the XML files using PHP DomDocument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php